# How to get applicationContextPath in dropwizard 1.0.0

Tags: java, dropwizard

We are using server configuration in yml file which looks like as below

```
server:
type: simple

connector:
  type: http
  port: 8061

applicationContextPath: /administration
adminContextPath: /admin

#disable the registration of default Jersey ExceptionMappers
registerDefaultExceptionMappers: false
```

I want to get "applicationContextPath" when I start my dropwizard service.

I am trying to get it using

```
environment.getApplicationContext().getContextPath();
```

but I am getting "/" i.e. default value. Is there anyway to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order get applicationContextPath we need to get ServerFactory from Configuration and parse it to SimpleServerFactory as below:

```
((SimpleServerFactory) getConfiguration().getServerFactory()).getApplicationContextPath()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@Override
    public void run(CustomAppConfiguration customAppConfiguration , Environment environment) throws Exception {
DefaultServerFactory factory = (DefaultServerFactory) customAppConfiguration .getServerFactory();
System.out.println("CONTEXT PATH: "+factory.getApplicationContextPath());
...
}
```

Comment: Which version of dropwizard are you using?

Comment: You are right. I'm using DW 0.9, I have not checked that for version 1.0. Doesn't this work for 1.0 too?

Comment: there is no such method getApplicationContextPath() in ServerFactory in 1.0 version

Answer (score 0):

If it's in your config file and you want to just read the value in as it exist in your config.yml, then I'd suggest making it part of your [Configuration class](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/getting-started.html#creating-a-configuration-class).  Values in your config can always be accessed this way regardless of whether dropwizard uses and treats those key/values in special manner internally.

The following worked for me in dropwizard 1.0.0:

MyApp.java:

```
public class MyApp extends Application<MyConfig> {
//...
@Override
public void run(MyConfig configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(configuration.contextPath);
//...
```

MyConfig.java

```
public class MyConfig extends Configuration {
//...
   @JsonProperty("applicationContextPath")
   public String contextPath;
//...
```

Comment: can i get it directly in my base configuration class using @JsonProperty("applicationContextPath") or do i have to nest it under Server configuration.

Comment: currently I am doing it something like this.
    `public class DefaultConfiguration extends Configuration {`

    `@JsonProperty("applicationContextPath")`
    `public String contextPath;`

    `@JsonProperty("database")`
    `private DataSourceFactory databaseConfiguration;`

Comment: The snippet you pasted should be fine.  You can add it directly to your base configuration class.

Comment: thanks for your inputs.. But i am getting null value for contextPath with the above configurations

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly what you can do in Dropwizard **version 1.3.8** if you are using simple server (without **https**) you can get applicationContextPath in following way:

```yaml
server:
  type: simple
  rootPath: /*
  applicationContextPath: /administration
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 8080
```

More info about `rootPath` can be found in [Dropwizard Configuration Reference](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-1.3.x/manual/configuration.html#man-configuration). So if you want to access:

1. **Application** REST endpoint `/books` (which is value of GET,
   POST or similar annotation in one of your Resource class methods) you can
   type URL like this `http://localhost:8080/administration/books`
2. **Metrics** (only accessible via **admin** context path) of your Dropwizard application then you create URL like this:
    `http://localhost:8080/admin/metrics`

Hope that helps. Cheers!